# optional chaining is not working: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Why optional chaining is not working here?

*.html*

```
 {{userItemModel?.item?.priceList[0]?.sellerUrl}}
```

It shows this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

> "@angular/core": "~10.1.1",
>
> "typescript": "~4.0.2"

```
 "priceList": [
                {
                    "amount": 14.5,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "sellerUrl": "https://www.bay.com/itm/Lear-6910-/33372049",
                    "basePrice": 15,
                    "discount": 10
                }
            ],
```

**Update**

**Use case 1:**

```
  Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 33 
in [                    {{userItemModel?.item?.priceList?.[0]?.sellerUrl}}
                    ] in
```

**Use case 2:**

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 33 in [

                    {{userItemModel?.item?.priceList?.[0].sellerUrl}}
                ] in
```

Comment: You can try the syntax from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Array_item_access_with_optional_chaining) (`priceList?.[0]`)

Comment: `priceList` is the one thing not included as "optional" in that example.

Comment: As `priceList` can be undefined - try with `userItemModel?.item?.priceList?.[0]?.sellerUrl`

Comment: @NickParsons No. This is not working. Please see the Update.

Comment: What is the `{{` - some sort of templating system?

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, this is Angular and it is on the Html page.

Comment: check this:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34385

Comment: @Chellappanவ Hmm... No solution for this then yet?

Comment: you can create custom pipe to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 8):

To correctly chain array access without an exception you should use `arr?.[index]`:

```js
var foo = {}
try{
  console.log(foo?.bar[0])
}
catch(e){
  console.log(e.message)
}
console.log(foo?.bar?.[0])
```

Edit: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34385) with angular at this time.

Comment: No. It is not working. Please see the Update.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to recreate your case with Typescript Playground to see what happen under the hood and to be sure I didn't make a typo.

Here a link where I did it : [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwMYQDIIM7CgXigbwCgoSoBDAWwHsBXAO2AC4o6aKAjCOAbmNKRpw4EOkhDMsiOgHNepKBggAbJVwCqcJROBTZfEuzKL4yCM1Ycuc0gBNMSWg3NtOPQgF9ChUJCgBJYAgKXAJ9KDBEFHQsAH5mEyjMYABtAF0Pb3BoNUU4AKCAWSobZRCieQRAijj-KozCBzosKBpc-Ioikq0oHK52ztK8ctJKoOZh%20RII02imKGSwydIJpdXKRzmARgAWADoAVgAaRdX5ASERMWYAIjUAZQARa%20PT08UVdU0bgAtgYDAMIwAPRAgDu4N2hhAuwcFCBlThqAgZDgAFoAGwATk2AAZUUCAMxEgDsACYcdtMc8Tq8oIZjJEzFBNkcaa87BgHPQtji2fJPKd0vyMo1mgAzBBwLAJNBJO7KVRwDRKEKtPpVAZKGK7UbVXbTRKxXbJHGpbXvRXK7hAA)

Here the exemple :

```
type PriceList = {
    amount: number;
    currency: string;
    sellerUrl: string;
    basePrice: number;
    discount: number;
}

type Item = {
    priceList?: PriceList[]
}
type UserItemModel = {
    item?: Item
}

const userItemModel: UserItemModel = {
    item: {
        priceList: [
            {
                amount: 14.5,
                currency: "USD",
                sellerUrl: "https://www.bay.com/itm/Lear-6910-/33372049",
                basePrice: 15,
                discount: 10
            }
        ]
    }
}
const firstPriceListSellerUrl = userItemModel?.item?.priceList?.[0]?.sellerUrl;
```

With this syntax, I don't see a problem.

Comment: This is Angular and on the HTML template. i.e. not on TS file.

Comment: You are right sorry. I didn't realize this difference. If you are blocked, you can hide the chainning logic inside a function inside the component TS file.

Comment: Yes, that is the exact thing where I have done until the Angular team will solve this issue. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34385